# Função pow() retorna INF

Tags: php

Galera é o seguinte to tentado faze potencia seguida de modulação ^ -> mod, mas a função pow() retorna "INF" e as demais funções como bcpow e bcpowmod retornam como funções inexistente dentro da class.
A versão do meu: PHP7.

```
$m = 726;
$d = 71;
$n = 1073;
$c = pow($m,$d) % $n // INF
$c = bcpow($m,$d) % $n; // Fatal error: undefined function bcpow()...
$c = bcpowmod($m,$d,$n); // Fatal error: undefined function bcpowmod()...
```

Alguém sabe o porque?

Comment: Está faltando um ponto e virgula na quarta linha. Veja aqui que está funcionando: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd75850c5babbbf53f4dd9701bee9d9bc9276fd7

Comment: No sandbox:
`pow() // retorna zero
bcpow // retorna 301
bcpowmod // retorna 436 correto.`

`Mas na minha class:
pow() // INF
bcpow()// undefined
bcpowmod // undefined`

Comment: Provavelmente a `bcmath` não está instalada. Um `phpinfo();` basta para verificar essas coisas. Quanto ao `pow`, é normal, afinal os números que você usou excedem a capacidade de armazenamento.

Comment: Sucesso!
Muito obrigado.